# Rotation of a disk - should there be a centripetal force?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

[image: f a]

See the diagram. The tension in the inextensible string should exert a torque causing a tangential acceleration on the rim of the disk. **But should there always be a force towards the centre of the circle if an object is describing a circular motion? And which force is doing this?** **Or is this rotating disk not describing a circular motion?** Do I misunderstand some concepts?

I think that objects having an angular velocity are moving in a circle. But a disk seems to be special.

Comment: The disc does have internal tensions, which pull the outer parts of the disc inward.

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318107848_Force_and_torque_of_a_string_on_a_pulley